# How to check for a framework's existence and run additional code if it exists, but project doesn't throw an error if framework not present

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am developing a iOS SDK and for the .a integration, the client has to include certain frameworks to get the code to run. Specifically for beacon support they have to include the CoreLocation framework. The goal is to allow them to use our SDK even if they don't have CoreLoation included. For cocoapods this is easy to handle, but I can't figure out how to handle it for static libraries.

I have tried __has_include() and checking if a class in framework exists, but I can't get it to run without either:
1) Hiding the class whether or not CoreLocation is included or
2) Throwing exceptions complaining about CoreLocation not being there

[Only SO question related, but solutions haven't helped](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642067/check-for-frameworks-existence-at-compile-time)

Comment: Update your question with the code giving you the problem.