# Check if framework has been added during compile time - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, llvm

I'm currently working on a project that has a class referencing the Security.h framework. Since this is a reusable class, and might be used in multiple projects, I wish to add a compile time check to **check whether the Security framework has been added to the project** or not. What I mean by added to the project is whether it has been added in the **Link Binary With Libraries** build phases for the current target.

Now, I know that questions with similar titles have been asked multiple times, and [this particular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15642067/check-for-frameworks-existence-at-compile-time) seemed to be super close to what I'm looking for, but I did not find an answer there either.

I've been using:

```
#ifdef __SENTINEL_VALUE_
..conditional code here..
#endif
```

code, but this **only** works if the framework header declares the sentinel value in the main header. Let me provide two examples to compare and contrast:

`SystemConfiguration.framework` has a framework header `SystemConfiguration.h` which includes all the sub headers, but also declares its own sentinel value, namely `_SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H`

Thus, checking it using `#ifdef _SYSTEMCONFIGURATION_H` works perfectly. However, for `Security.framework`, the framework header, `Security.h` does not declare its own sentinel value. Each of its sub headers declare their own sentinel value, but since they are being imported in `Security.h`, the sentinel value gets **defined**. Therefore, even if `Security.framework` is not included in the project (not linked in the build phases), an `#ifndef` for one of its sub headers returns a false value, since the sentinel value is defined owing to its import in the `Security.h` file (not to mention that this approach of checking for a sub header of a framework header makes me feel a little sad).

So, my question is: For a unique case like `Security.framework`, what would be the appropriate **compile time** check to check whether the framework has been added to the **Link Binary With Libraries** phase (if such a check exists).

Additionally, I know of the `NSClassFromString()` method and the `NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE` macros, but I'm not looking for a run-time solution.

Thanks in advance all!

Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried Product>Generate Output>Preprocessed File in xCode?

Comment: I have not tried it, but how will that help me with respect to a compile time check?

Comment: It shows you what the compiler is seeing.  You can see if what you want declared is being declared in this file.  Not sure if it will answer your question, but thought I'd suggest it.

Answer (score 2):

The link phase follows the compile phase, so there is no way the compiler can tell whether a framework will be linked to the project.

If your project's product is a *framework*, *dynamic* library or an executable, you just link your binary against the Security framework, and you are fine.

If your project's product is a *static* library, you need to confirm that the project which produces the final executable binary will link against the Security framework. The recommended way is to provide an install and usage documentation, and possibly a sample.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yep, I'm aware of the fact that the linking phase comes in after the compile phase. My question is more towards whether the framework is included, and whether there's a directive to definitively check whether a symbol is defined or not.

Comment: Testing whether a symbol from the library is defined isn't reliable, since you could #include/#import the public headers, though a client may not link against the framework. This would result in undefined symbol errors when the final executable will be build. On the other hand, if you use any symbol in your library sources, you know that you include the header anyway, otherwise you would get compile errors.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a little too late, but for future references for whoever encounters this kind of problem try this

```
BOOL isFrameworkLoaded = (NSClassFromString(@"MyClassNameFromTheFramework") != nil);
```

Can't take the credit, here's a link to the original post

https://stackoverflow.com/a/7333589/4160199